# Integral of 1/[4^(-x) + 4^(x+1)]

Tags: calculus

I am stuck, I tried to use $u = 4^{-x}$

$$\int \frac{dx}{4^{-x} + 4^{x+1}}dx$$

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \int \frac{dx}{4^{-x}+4^{x+1}} &= \int dx \frac{4^x}{1+4 \cdot 4^{2 x}} \\ &= \int dx \frac{e^{a x}}{1+4\, e^{2 a x}}\\ &= \frac1{4 a}\int \frac{dy}{\frac14+y^2} \\ &= \frac1{4 \log{2}} \arctan{(2 y)} +C \\ &= \frac1{4 \log{2}} \arctan{(2 \cdot 4^x)}+C\end{align}$$

Note that $a=\log{4} = 2 \log{2}$ in the above.

Comment: Can I express 2 * 4**x in terms of 2? I got the same answer but according to the solution's manual it has to be 2 ** (2x+ 1)

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  I would suggest that the main problem is just unfamiliarity with integrating powers of numbers other than $e$, and if we put it in terms of $e^u$ instead of $4^x$ it should look simpler.  So, substitute
$$e^u=4^x\ ,\quad\hbox{that is,}\quad u=x\ln4\ .$$
Then
$$\int\frac{dx}{4^{-x}+4^{x+1}}
  =\frac{1}{\ln4}\int\frac{du}{e^{-u}+4e^u}
  =\frac{1}{\ln4}\int\frac{e^u\,du}{1+4(e^u)^2}\ .$$
See if you can take it from here.